# Selection in contentEditable <div> collapses as soon as I click a button

Tags: javascript, dom, selection, contenteditable

As can be seen below, instead of `<button>` or `<input>` I have used `<div>` to create my UI buttons. Now the problem is as soon as I click any of the buttons, the selection in the edit area (a contentEditable `<div>`) collapses.

Interestingly if I use `<button>` instead of `<div>` to create my UI buttons, everything works like a charm. I have seen this question asked many times before on stackoverflow, but they all use `<button>`. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: When you click anywhere on a page that is selectable the existing selection will collapse.

Comment: @Nick Which is why I am seeking a solution here

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858725/how-to-maintain-selection-after-click-in-html

Comment: @Nick Thank you Nick. Making my <div> buttons 'unselectable' did the trick. Would you like to put your reponse in an answer here so I can make it 'accepted' answer. Thnks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that your `div` elements are selectable, so clicking on them automatically collapses the existing selection. You can work around this by making them "unselectable" by setting the [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) CSS property to `none`. This is [supported](https://caniuse.com/user-select-none) in most current browsers.